# What to put into the CFBundleIdentifier of an Apple helpbook?

Tags: macos

The `Info.plist` file of an Apple helpbook (.help file) contains a field `CFBundleIdentifier`, which according to Apple is the "help book ID" (see [Authoring Apple Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html)).

The provided example gives "com.mycompany.surfwriter.help" as a value; effectively the bundle ID of the application with a ".help" appendix. If I look into .help files of real applications (for example BBEdit), I see the same pattern.

However when I create a help book like this, Help Viewer doesn't open the help book. But when I remove the ".help", so that the bundle ID in the help book is identical to the app bundle ID, it works.

Am I doing something wrong? Is my interpetation - that you should append `.help` to your app bundle ID in the help book - correct?

For reference, here is an example Info.plist that does *not* work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en_us</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.esclepiusllc.Rex-T.help</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>ReX-T Help</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>hbwr</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>HPDBookAccessPath</key>
    <string>start.html</string>
    <key>HPDBookIconPath</key>
    <string>shrd/appicon.png</string>
    <key>HPDBookIndexPath</key>
    <string>HelpBookIndex.helpindex</string>
    <key>HPDBookKBProduct</key>
    <string>com.esclepiusllc.ReX-T</string>
    <key>HPDBookTitle</key>
    <string>ReX-T Help</string>
    <key>HPDBookTopicListCSSPath</key>
    <string>sty/topiclist.css</string>
    <key>HPDBookTopicListTemplatePath</key>
    <string>sty/topiclist.xquery</string>
    <key>HPDBookType</key>
    <string>3</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As soon as I replace "com.esclepiusllc.Rex-T.help" with "com.esclepiusllc.Rex-T", it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add the name of the help bundle and help folder to your app's `Info.plist`. See [“How to Register Your Help Book” in the *Apple Help Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/registering_help/registering_help.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH207-BHAHHAAE):

> For Cocoa and Java applications, you can take advantage of automatic help book registration by adding the help book name and location to your information property list (`Info.plist`) file. […]
>
> […]
>
> To register a help book, you need to include the `CFBundleHelpBookFolder` and `CFBundleHelpBookName` keys in your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Thanks, but I did set these.